# Where is the difference, when the Task Scheduler starts a task as user VS. when the user starts a task?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

Scenario: I set up a task so that a certain .exe is run as user "A" when any user logs on the computer.
When I start the program via GUI it all works as intended. But when I let the Task Scheduler do its thing, the .exe appears in Task Manager as expected, but the program does not do anything.

So there must be some difference between when the Task Scheduler is starting this program as user A vs. user A starting this program, but where?

Already tried a delay after logon but that did not change anything.

I'm on a Windows 10 machine and the program I refer to is https://github.com/dechamps/laplock

Comment: The task is perhaps not interactive. Have you defined the task as "Run only when user is logged on"?

Comment: Nope, it's set to the other option. And yeah it's not interactive, it doesn't need to be, it should run quietly in the backround and lock Windows when the lid is closed. Works when started directly, does not work when started as scheduled task or as service, even though the process is running.